# How do I schedule a query in the new BigQuery UI?

Tags: google-bigquery

There is a 'schedule query' button in the old BigQuery web UI, but I could not see it in the new web UI. Is this hidden somewhere or does it not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beta release of scheduled queries does not include support for the Cloud Console BigQuery UI.

Edit: the Cloud Console UI now supports scheduled queries. You can find instructions [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query).

Comment: There was an update to new UI, you can now schedule queries using new UI @Balkan. There is new button under query compeser.